# How to get only internal string without delimiter with .match(regEx) in js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

Hello I am trying to parse an xml string with js. My string is similar to the one below. I am using .match() function with regular expressions.

```
var str='<rate val="xyz"></rate> <rate val="klm"></rate> <rate val="mnp"></rate>';
var result=str.match(/val="(.+?)"/g);
```

I want to get a result array like:

```
 ["xyz","klm","mnp"]
```

But it gives me as

```
["rate val="xyz"","rate val="klm"","rate val="mnp""]
```

How can I get only values without attribute names?

Comment: Look up "non-capturing groups".

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression) should help you.

Comment: I noticed you reverted my edit -- you shouldn't start your question with "Hello" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351589/6358346

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of messing with regex, you could use a combination of `filter` and `map` to get the properties of the elements in to an array as you require:

```
var str = '<rate val="xyz"></rate> <rate val="klm"></rate> <rate val="mnp"></rate>';
var result = $(str).filter('rate').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('val');    
}).get();

console.log(result);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gchnsu9o/)